# Trying to make a "div" selector in page: JavaScript TypeError

Tags: javascript, html

So I keep getting the same error:

```
index.html:184 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
    at xpxp (index.html:184)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (index.html:127)
```

and always seems to indicate to these 4 lines

```js
if (core_me.style.display === "none")
```

I have been trying to move the script part all over and also to change the `if` to simple toggles.

Thank you in advance for your time!

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
        <head>
            <title>CV TOMAZ LIMA</title>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
            
        </head>
        <script>
                function meme( event ) {
                    var me = document.getElementById("me");
                    var xp = document.getElementById("xp");
                    var edu = document.getElementById("edu");
                    var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
                    var core_xp = document.getElementById("core_xp");
                    var core_edu = document.getElementById("core_edu");
                    var core_contact = document.getElementById("core_contact");
                    var core_me = document.getElementById("core_me");
                    if (core_me.style.display === "none") {
                        me.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
                        core_me.style.display = "block";
                        xp.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        core_xp.style.display = "none";
                        core_edu.style.display = "none";
                        edu.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        core_contact.style.display = "none";
                        contact.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                    } 
                    else {
                            core_me.style.display = "none";
                        }
                }
                function xpxp( event ) {
                    var me = document.getElementById("me");
                    var xp = document.getElementById("xp");
                    var edu = document.getElementById("edu");
                    var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
                    var core_xp = document.getElementById("core_xp");
                    var core_edu = document.getElementById("core_edu");
                    var core_contact = document.getElementById("core_contact");
                    var core_me = document.getElementById("core_me");
                    if (core_xp.style.display === "none") {
                        xp.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
                        core_xp.style.display = "block";
                        me.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        core_me.style.display = "none";
                        contact.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        core_edu.style.display = "none";
                        edu.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        core_contact.style.display = "none";
                        contact.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                    } 
                    else {
                            core_xp.style.display = "none";
                        }
                }
                function eduedu( event ) {
                    var me = document.getElementById("me");
                    var xp = document.getElementById("xp");
                    var edu = document.getElementById("edu");
                    var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
                    var core_xp = document.getElementById("core_xp");
                    var core_edu = document.getElementById("core_edu");
                    var core_contact = document.getElementById("core_contact");
                    var core_me = document.getElementById("core_me");
                    if (core_edu.style.display === "none") {
                        edu.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
                        core_edu.style.display = "block";
                        me.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        core_xp.style.display = "none";
                        xp.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        core_me.style.display = "none";
                        core_contact.style.display = "none";
                        contact.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                    } 
                    else {
                            core_edu.style.display = "none";
                        }
                }
                function contactcontact( event ) {
                    var me = document.getElementById("me");
                    var xp = document.getElementById("xp");
                    var edu = document.getElementById("edu");
                    var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
                    var core_xp = document.getElementById("core_xp");
                    var core_edu = document.getElementById("core_edu");
                    var core_contact = document.getElementById("core_contact");
                    var core_me = document.getElementById("core_me");
                    if (core_contact.style.display === "none") {
                        contact.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
                        core_contact.style.display = "block";
                        me.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        core_xp.style.display = "none";
                        xp.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        core_edu.style.display = "none";
                        edu.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        core_me.style.display = "none";
                    } 
                    else {
                            core_.style.display = "none";
                        }
                }
                
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            </script>
    
        <body>
            <div class="top">
            
            </div>
            <div class="bk">
                <div class="L">
                    <img class="avatar" src="images/avatar.jpg" alt="TOMAZ LIMA" width="300vw" height="300vh">
                    <h1 class="txt_e">TOMAZ LIMA</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="R">
                    <div class="top_bar">
                        <div onclick="meme( event )" class="me">ABOUT ME
                        </div>
                        <div class="xp" onclick="xpxp( event )">EXPERIENCE
                        </div>
                        <div class="edu" onclick="eduedu( event )">EDUCATION
                        </div>
                        <div class="contact" onclick="contactcontact( event )">CONTACT
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="core">
                        <div class="core_me" style="display:none;">
                        core_me
                        </div>
                        <div class="core_xp" style="display:none;">
                        core_xp
                        </div>
                        <div class="core_edu" style="display:none;">
                        core_edu
                        </div>
                        <div class="core_contact" style="display:none;">
                        core_contact
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <script>
                function meme( event ) {
                    var me = document.getElementById("me");
                    var xp = document.getElementById("xp");
                    var edu = document.getElementById("edu");
                    var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
                    var corexp = document.getElementById("core_xp");
                    var coreedu = document.getElementById("core_edu");
                    var corecontact = document.getElementById("core_contact");
                    var coreme = document.getElementById("core_me");
                    if (coreme.style.display === "none") {
                        me.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
                        coreme.style.display = "block";
                        xp.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        corexp.style.display = "none";
                        coreedu.style.display = "none";
                        edu.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        corecontact.style.display = "none";
                        contact.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                    } 
                    else {
                            core_me.style.display = "none";
                        }
                }
                function xpxp( event ) {
                    var me = document.getElementById("me");
                    var xp = document.getElementById("xp");
                    var edu = document.getElementById("edu");
                    var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
                    var corexp = document.getElementById("core_xp");
                    var coreedu = document.getElementById("core_edu");
                    var corecontact = document.getElementById("core_contact");
                    var coreme = document.getElementById("core_me");
                    if (corexp.style.display === "none") {
                        xp.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
                        corexp.style.display = "block";
                        me.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        coreme.style.display = "none";
                        contact.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        coreedu.style.display = "none";
                        edu.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        corecontact.style.display = "none";
                        contact.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                    } 
                    else {
                            core_xp.style.display = "none";
                        }
                }
                function eduedu( event ) {
                    var me = document.getElementById("me");
                    var xp = document.getElementById("xp");
                    var edu = document.getElementById("edu");
                    var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
                    var corexp = document.getElementById("core_xp");
                    var coreedu = document.getElementById("core_edu");
                    var corecontact = document.getElementById("core_contact");
                    var coreme = document.getElementById("core_me");
                    if (coreedu.style.display === "none") {
                        edu.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
                        coreedu.style.display = "block";
                        me.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        corexp.style.display = "none";
                        xp.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        coreme.style.display = "none";
                        corecontact.style.display = "none";
                        contact.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                    } 
                    else {
                            core_edu.style.display = "none";
                        }
                }
                function contactcontact( event ) {
                    var me = document.getElementById("me");
                    var xp = document.getElementById("xp");
                    var edu = document.getElementById("edu");
                    var contact = document.getElementById("contact");
                    var corexp = document.getElementById("core_xp");
                    var coreedu = document.getElementById("core_edu");
                    var corecontact = document.getElementById("core_contact");
                    var coreme = document.getElementById("core_me");
                    if (corecontact.style.display === "none") {
                        contact.style.backgroundColor = "#000";
                        corecontact.style.display = "block";
                        me.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        corexp.style.display = "none";
                        xp.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        coreedu.style.display = "none";
                        edu.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
                        coreme.style.display = "none";
                    } 
                    else {
                            core_.style.display = "none";
                        }
                }
                
            
            
            
            
            
            
            
            </script>
            
        </body>
    </html>
```

Style:

```css
    body{margin:0;font-size: 16px; font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif; background-color: #2F349D;}
    
    a{text-decoration: none;}
    
    h1,h2,h3,p{margin:0;}   
    
    
    .top{
        display: inlineblock;
        height: 10vh;
        background-color: #232776;
    }
    
    .bk{
        display: flex;
        padding: 1vh;
    }
    
    .L{
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        width: 19vw;
        padding: 10vh 5vw 0;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .R{
        display: block;
        width: 60vw;
        height: 80vh;
        padding: 4vh;
    }
    img.avatar{
        
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 2px solid white;
        border-color:#fff;
        }
        
    h1.txt_e{
        padding: 5vh 2px;
    }
    
    .top_bar{
        display: flex;
        direction: row;
        height: 15vh;
        width: 60vw;
    }
    
    .me{
        display: block;
        width:15vw;
        height:5vh;
        text-align: center;
        background-color:#fff;
        padding: 5vh 0vw;
        font-size: 4vh;
    }
    
    .xp{
        display: block;
        width:15vw;
        height:5vh;
        text-align: center;
        background-color:#fff;
        padding: 5vh 0vw;
        font-size: 4vh;
    }
    
    .edu{
        display: block;
        width:15vw;
        height:5vh;
        text-align: center;
        background-color:#fff;
        padding: 5vh 0vw;
        font-size: 4vh;
    }
    
    .contact{
        display: block;
        width:15vw;
        height:5vh;
        text-align: center;
        background-color:#fff;
        padding: 5vh 0vw;
        font-size: 4vh;
    }
    
    .core{
        position: relative; 
    }
    
    .core_me{
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        height: 60vh;
        width: 60vw;
        background-color:#fff;
    }
    
    .core_xp{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        height: 60vh;
        width: 60vw;
        background-color:#fff;
    }
    
    .core_edu{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        height: 60vh;
        width: 60vw;
        background-color:#fff;
    }
    
    .core_contact{
        display: none;
        position: absolute;
        height: 60vh;
        width: 60vw;
        background-color:#fff;
    }
    
    div[onclick] {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Comment: <div class="core_me" style="display:none;"> class is not id, if you search by id, your element needs to have id="core_me"

Comment: Nice catch @NadiaChibrikova.

Comment: The code you posted is extremely long. You will help your helpers by reducing it to the minimum needed to exemplify your use case.

Answer (score 2):

You are not getting the element. `getElementById` returns `null` if no element with the specified ID exists. And as far as I can see, you used `class` instead of `id`.

Take this for example:

```
<div class="xp" onclick="xpxp( event )">EXPERIENCE</div>
```

You are using the wrong attribute. Should be:

```
<div id="xp" onclick="xpxp( event )">EXPERIENCE</div>
```

Then you can `document.getElementById('xp')`. Also remember that IDs should be unique. There shouldn't be more than one element with the same ID. In case you need that, you should probably be using `class` attribute!

Comment: thank you very muck!! lost track of it with all the changes

Comment: Por nada! Abrazo.

Answer (score 1):

What is `core_me` and where is it defined? It looks like the system is interpreting it as `null` so you need to go make sure you can read that object from this function.

EDIT: It looks like another commenter has the correct answer. It's a mismatch between `class` and `id`.